# "Incompatible pointer types" warnings in Xcode 4.2 (iOS 5.0)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4, ios5

When I upgraded my Xcode from 4.0 to 4.2 (with iOS 5.0 SDK), I start getting multiple warnings in my code where I am using the code:

```
self.delegate = self;
```

> Warning: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSObject *' from 'MyClass *'

Here, `self.delegate` is set to `MyDelegate` object & `self` is `MyClass` object.

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myResponse:(NSDictionary *)response;
- (void)myError:(id)errorData;
@end


@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyDelegate> {

}
```

These warnings do not come in 4.0.

What should I do to suppress these warnings?

Comment: what does your .h file look like? does it declare that the class implements `<MyDelegate>`?

Comment: also, why are you declaring your class' delegate to be itself? doesn't this defeat the purpose of delegation?

Comment: Can you post the `@interface` and `@protocol` declarations for your class and protocol?

Comment: I am declaring a property @property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject <MyDelegate> *delegate; in MyClass.h and MyDelegate protocol is also defined in the same interface class. Normally the delegate is set to other objects but due to some business logic I need to execute delegate methods by MyClass object itself.

Comment: does the top of your .h file say `@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyDelegate>` ?

Comment: Can you post the entire .h file? Let's see what instance variables and properties you have...

Comment: Is that self.delegate = self; in your init method per chance?

Answer (score -1):

You should declare your delegate like this

```
id<MyDelegate> delegate;
```

and the property as

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)   id <MyDelegate>   delegate;
```